# Django - use Radio Buttons instead of Select for form component

Tags: python, django

I have several `ModelForm`s used to build surveys, whose models contain lots of questions (>30 each). At the moment, the multiple choice questions are represented as a `<select>` element, but to improve UX I'd like to change this to radio buttons.

As it's a `ModelForm`, I rely on django to automatically create the fields on the form. So while I know it's possible to change each field on the form by doing this:

```
class SurveyForm(ModelForm):
   ...
   field_one = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

these definitions don't currently exist, and I'd have to create at least 150 of those definitions. I'm sure there's a better way to override where the widget choice is made (perhaps extending ModelForm?). Or alternatively, could I do this by attaching the widget to the field definition?

I've taken a look through the Django docs and source, but I can't find where the widget is chosen for model fields with a `choices` kwarg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first thought was that you could use [`formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides). However, that won't work, because you only want to override the widget for `models.CharField`s that have choices, not all `models.CharField`s.

One approach would be to loop through the form's fields in the `__init__` method, and change any widgets from `forms.Select` to `forms.RadioInput`.

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('field_one', 'field_two', ...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            if isinstance(field.widget, forms.Select):
                field.widget = forms.RadioSelect()
```

If you have many forms like this, you could extract the functionality into a mixin.

Answer (score 11):

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'field_one': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

May be you'd like this:

```
widgets = {field: forms.RadioSelect() for field in ['field_one', 'field_two']}
```

Comment: I don't want to enumerate the fields like that though, there are ~30 fields in each form, and this is too tightly coupled to changes in surveys.

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's just the option. You choose the answer.

Comment: In my case, I do want to enumerate the fields, so thanks for tipping me off to this!